# What is the Antonym for depleted?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, antonyms

I have searched every online dictionary and can not find a word which means, not depleted."Undepleted" is apparently not a word. I want to say

> "His funds remain not depleted by unnecessary expenses"

but "not depleted" and "remain full" doesn't cut it for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you wish to indicate that his funds remained unaffected.i.e. neither decreased nor increased, despite unnecessary expenditures? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy - My feeling is that his funds were *preserved* because he didn't spent money in unnecessary expenses. Peter, may you confirm ?

Comment: Who says ***undepleted*** isn't a word? Tell that to [over 22,000 published writers in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22undepleted%22)

Comment: [Undepleted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undepleted) in Wiktionary: 1. that has not been depleted.

Comment: It's a bit of a strange sentence. Are you trying to say that he does not make any unnecessary expenses, or that they are small relative to his funds, or that the funds are replenished to compensate?

Comment: What kind of antonym are you looking for? The logical negation or the opposite end of the spectrum? Depleted= empty, so the logical opposite is 'not empty', but the other end of the spectrum is 'totally filled'. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Do you want to indicate a surplus? Or just business as usual?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, *[undepleted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deplete?s=t)* is an established word as pointed out by a couple of users in comments.

However, if you are looking for alternative words, you can consider **[unaltered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unaltered)**

Unaltered (adj.)

> not altered, changed, or modified

[Dictionary.com]

In your case,

> His funds remain **unaltered**, even with all his unnecessary expenditures

Comment: 'Unaltered' means unchanged and could apply to a fully depleted account

Answer (score 2):

Either "replete" or archaic (as used in *Dracula*) "eked out"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research in your post. I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.

Comment: Follow Rathony's suggestion!  After that, you could quote two sentences  from "Dracula" with the words you suggest.  You should also search some dictionaries for the antonyms of the words you suggest.  If the sentences and the antonyms bear out your draft answer, particularly in the case of "eked out" (which means something different today), you will have an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *undepleted*, I could indeed not find it in either the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=undepleted), nor the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/undepleted). So, you could argue the word 'does not exist', but as FumbleFingers and Rathony pointed out in the comments, the word is in general use and has been defined in other dictionaries. I would thus argue *undepleted* is an actual word.

Now, while I am not a native speaker, I personally feel that *undepleted* implies a process of depletion, e.g. at the current rate of spending, depletion is guaranteed to happen sometime in the future, but has not happened yet.

If this is what you are trying to convey, then yes, *undepleted* would be a antonym. If you however desire to convey that his funds remain the same since they are not affected by any spending, I would advise BiscuitBoy's answer of *unaltered*.

Finally, since there has been some confusion in the comments regarding the actual spending, maybe you should rephrase to make clear that either he is not spending unnecessarily (use *unaltered*), or spending too lavishly (use *undepleted*).